# How to scale TextView in android and keep it in center

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to do a layout with dynamic scaling of test view. The layout looks like [image: the following] - see bottom left corner.

Now that portion is a composite control. The circle scales just fine, but I can't figure out how to make the text positioned perfectly in the middle while scaling properly. I want the text at let's say 50% of the container size and positioned perfectly in the center. RelativeLayout only allows for absolute values, and I can't seem to get the weighting working with text view for linear layout with textview.

Composite control:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/VarioCircle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="Vario Circle"

        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/circle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/VarioText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"

            android:text="200"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Overal layout:

```
 <com.proflite.VarioView
     android:id="@+id/Vario"
         android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the TextView inside of container. And set Gravity (Views attribute) to Center.
Set TextViews width and height to wrap_content.
This will make TextView centered in it's container.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

This will get TextView centered inside of FrameLayout

Comment: While it does center it, the scaling doesn't apply. I've posted code to show what I tried so far

Comment: To make TextView exactly 50% height of it's container you will need to write some code - it's not posible to do it with just layout xml's.

But I doubt that you need that. You can set your containers height to some DP and your TextView to some SP. e.g. container 200dp and your TextViews text size 20SP.
This would scale nice in different screen sizes (densities). 
Or is there another reason why you want to make scaling?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/VarioCircle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:contentDescription="Vario Circle"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/circle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/VarioText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="200"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="monospace" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make an Button widget and set an image as background which has .png format, having transparent background.

Like this:
[image]

After that Make sure to save it as .png

1)Then go to your xml layout create a Button or ImageButton widget.
2)Set this pic saved as a background image ( `android:background="@drawable/yourcircle"`)
3)then finally you can put any text inside ( `android:text="blabla"`) + you can change it from the code for sure using `Button.setText("blablabla")`
4)You will also want to change the font size using Button.setTextSize(49) for example.
5)Finally to make it in the center, `android:gravity="center"`